# How to retain the order of data sent in select statement in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my query i want the same order in which i am sending data but order is getting changed because of join.

```
SELECT 
ID 
,ISNULL(CAST(UE.Value AS INT),0) ,
CASE 
WHEN P.RTLSTagID IS NULL THEN 1 --UntaggedPatient (EnumLastSeenColumnDisplayType) 
WHEN P.RTLSTagID IS NOT NULL AND P.RTLSLocationID IS NULL THEN 2 --PatientWithMissingTag (EnumLastSeenColumnDisplayType) 
ELSE 0 
END
FROM dbo.fnParseString('3247136,3247324,3247070,3247282,3247052', ',') TP 
INNER JOIN Patient P WITH (NOLOCK) ON P.PatientID = TP.ID 
INNER JOIN vwUnitLocation VUL WITH (NOLOCK) ON VUL.LocationID = p.HomeLocationID 
INNER JOIN UnitEnvironmentProperty UE WITH (NOLOCK) ON UE.UnitID = VUL.UnitID 
WHERE UE.EnvironmentPropertyID = 276
```

i want the output to be

```
ID      (No column name)
3247136 3
3247324 6
3247070 3
3247282 3
3247052 3
```

but output is appearing this way

```
ID      (No column name)
3247136 3
3247070 3
3247282 3
3247052 3
3247324 6
```

Comment: What is your logical order?

Comment: your statement has no  `order by` which means the database is free to deliver the rows in any order

Comment: patient id is getting reorder i sending the patient id has 3247136,3247324,3247070,3247282,3247052 but after execution of select statement its resorted as 3247136 
3247070 
3247282 
3247052 
3247324 its because of unit id which is last column in select statement

Comment: yes the database by default its ordering by unit id which i don't want it to happen.based on this select later i need to update data .Because of the reorder data is getting updated wrongly

Comment: the select statement has 3 columns and output you are showing has only 2 columns. Add more details.

Comment: ID (No column name) (No column name)
3247136 0 3
3247070 0 3
3247282 0 3
3247052 1 3
3247324 0 6

Comment: i forget to display last column

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to declare a temp table with identity column and use it in the query.

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (tempId INT IDENTITY(1,1), Id INT)

INSERT INTO @Temp (Id)
SELECT Id FROM dbo.fnParseString('3247136,3247324,3247070,3247282,3247052', ',')
```

Now use @temp in the main query with `ORDER BY tempId`

```
SELECT ...

FROM @Temp TP --Using @Temp table
   JOIN Patient P WITH (NOLOCK) ON P.PatientID = TP.ID 
   JOIN vwUnitLocation VUL WITH (NOLOCK) ON VUL.LocationID = p.HomeLocationID 
   JOIN UnitEnvironmentProperty UE WITH (NOLOCK) ON UE.UnitID = VUL.UnitID 
WHERE UE.EnvironmentPropertyID = 276
ORDER BY TP.tempId --Ordering by tempId
```